# Download Web PI components to install them manually?

Tags: iis, web-platform-installer

I have a new Test IIS server that my IT Ops "buddies" refuse to connect to the internet - but I'd like to update it with some of the latest components that the Web Platform Installer makes so easy!

Is there any way to download each of these components so they can be copied onto the box and installed manually?  e.g. Launch WebPI locally but choose to save the install files?

I know I can download .Net4, MVC3 individually, but what about things like "IIS Recommended Configuration"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is to hassle your Ops guys until they give in and give you temporary internet access, install everything you need, then revoke it.